# How to convert Arabic string to UTF-8 using C#?

Tags: c#, utf-8

I need to convert some arabic text to utf-8 and convert it to Hexa I made some codes but it turns the output to like what in next image.

Codes I trid :

```
string myName = _name.Text;
string myNameLength  = _name.TextLength.ToString("X2");
byte[] nameByte = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(myName);
var hexStringName = BitConverter.ToString(nameByte);
hexStringCo = hexStringCo.Replace("-", "");
```

Picture
[image]

Comment: If you want UTF8, you need to use `Encoding.UTF8` instead of `Encoding.Default`. Apart from that, your code looks fine. Except for the second line, which is useless and can be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting the utf8 bytes is:

```cs
string name = "عبود";
byte[] utf8 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(name);
var hex = BitConverter.ToString(utf8);
hex = hex.Replace("-", "");
Console.WriteLine(hex); // D8B9D8A8D988D8AF
```

What you *do* with those is up to you; there's zero chance that a hex string was rendered with the replacement character (aka �), so: you're doing something else that we can't see. Maybe show us what you're *doing* with the value once you have it.